# Active/Passive Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

Is below sentence passive present perfect tense or present perfect tense and married is adjective.

They have been married for 20 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Married* is an adjective here.

The verb "to marry" refers to the ceremony or legal action which changes the people's state, not to the state. So the passive "be married" (more commonly "get married") is something which happens on a particular date, not over a period.